# table-layout=fixed and one col without specified width-property sets table width to 100% in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, width, tablelayout

i want a table to render with minimum width according to its content, but IE7 insists on expanding it to 100% width.

The following little snippet works fine in Firefox and IE8, but not in IE7:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      table { table-layout: fixed  }
      td { padding: 0 10px; border: 1px solid blue;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
<table>
      <tr>
        <td>Column with variable width</td>
        <td style="width: 100px;">Column 2</td>
        <td style="width: 100px;">Column 3</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

- I have a table with table-layout: fixed.
- I have specified the width of all cells except the first one.
- In the first column, i want the browser to determine the width based on the content
- As I don't know the width of the first column, I cannot (and do not want to) specify the width of the table.

Now, the problem in IE7 is that the table is rendered to 100% width. So the first col has not the minimum width that is required to display its content but takes up all the space to make the table 100% width.

Here is what i found out so far:

- when i remove "table-layout: fixed" from the table, the table will not expand to 100%. Unfortunatly, that's not an option for me.
- when i set the table-width to a very small size (like e.g. 10px), the first col will not be expanded to the minimum required width, but will disappear entirerly.
- i tried to set "display: inline;" for the table, but that has no effects on the width.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advace,
Pitter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If only purpose of `table-layout: fixed` is to fix widths of cells, then you can add `DIV`s with desired width inside `TD` and get rid of `table-layout: fixed` for table.

Comment: I guess that'll have to do. Although i don't like the taste of changing huge amounts of source-code just for IE7. Looking forward to the day when our client abandons IE7-support ;-)

Comment: Another option is to use JavaScript to add IE7-specific styles and elements while keeping static code clean. BTW, it makes sense to try to convince clients to partially drop IE7 support by using independent simplified stylesheet. For example, there is ready-to-use [stylesheet for IE6](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/blog/about/universal_internet_explorer_6_css/). (I prefer to use my own one though, while I currently don't support both IE6 and IE7.)

Answer (score 1):

The [CSS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#fixed-table-layout) on `table-layout: fixed`:

> With this (fast) algorithm, the horizontal layout of the table **does
>   not depend on the contents of the cells**; it only depends on the
>   table's width, the width of the columns, and borders or cell spacing.

So you should definitely try to achieve whatever you need `table-layout: fixed` for by some other means.